# regex to disallow whitespace

Tags: asp.net, regex, regex-negation

I'm looking for a regex that will allow Alpha Numeric and most all special characters except white space. It should be usable in c#. It would be nice if .net supported posix style but I can't seem to get it to work. TIA

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you don't want to match all but whitespace. Can you show some examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure \S (note capitalization) is the non-whitespace character class.

Comment: thanks, my brain must be dead today. that was an embarrassingly simple question.

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of: `[^\s]+` should do the trick.

This roughly translates as "match one or more consecutive characters that are not whitespace" (`\s` matches a space, tab, or line break).